# XMPP Framework issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios4

I am facing issue in XMPP framework when integrating in another project. Its giving me error after connecting to socket and disconnecting..

```
Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo=0xb2cab50 {NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}
```

XMPP framework working fine stand alone. I integrated same code but getting this error.
What might be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You should ping your server (Send an `XMPPPing`) with intervals, to tell server that you're alive and your socket should not be closed !

You can also configure `XMPPAutoPing` module, but notice that the default interval for that is 60 seconds !

You can also send a `Keep Alive` Packet, in short time intervals. By default it is being sent each 120 seconds by the framework, but you can configure it as you want in `XMPPStream.h` .